# How to access a AR scene in Xcode (Swift)?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

For older Xcode versions, I was able to get a scene by accessing the .scnassets folder.

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
```

However, the newer Xcode version no longer has this folder and replaced it with:
Experience.rcproject

How do I access a scene from this .rcproject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
let boxAnchor = try! Expereience.loadBox()
//you replace .loadBox() to .loadWhatever() you named your scene

arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
```